# Entity Framework Core - Configure Entity has a virtual collection which can join on 2 different columns (OR) condition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET 7 and EF Core 7.

I have an entity `Student` with two properties: `StudentId` (primary key) and the `GradeId`.

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid GradeId { get; set; }
}
```

I have the `Course` class, which has course information.

```
public class Course
{
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There are two associated types of courses with `Students`: the special course that is registered only for students and the courses associated with the student's grade.

```
public class StudentRegisteredCourse
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
}

public class GradeCourse
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid GradeId { get; set; }
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

For example, I have John in Grade 10. With grade 10, the student must have Math 10 and Physic 10 courses. John registered for the C# Foundation course for himself.

So, John will have three courses: Math 10, Physic 10, and C# Foundation.

Currently, I can design the `Student`'s associated courses with two virtual collections `RegisteredCourses` and `GradeCourses`.

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid GradeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentRegisteredCourse> RegisteredCourses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GradeCourse> GradeCourses { get; set; }
}
```

With the `GradeCourses`, it needs to join on `GradeId` instead of the primary key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany(c => c.GradeCourses)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.GradeId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.GradeId);
```

With this design, it's working for me and I can filter a list of students who have a specific course.

```
var studentOfSpanishCourse = dbContext.Students
                                      .Where(c => c.RegisteredCourses.Any(c => c.CourseId = 'Spanish course id') || c.GradeCourses.Any(c => c.CourseId = 'Spanish course id'));
```

However, as we can see, we need to filter both collections `RegisteredCourses` and `GradeCourses` to have the student list of Spanish courses.

I am trying to simplify it by finding a way to make Student will have a virtual collection only, named `CoursesOfStudent`. The `CoursesOfStudent` is a union of all of `StudentCourse` and `GradeCourse`.

So, in the place using `Student` to filter, we just need to 'where' on single collection only.

To do that, I created a view `CourseOfStudent`, which unions the `StudentRegisteredCourse` and `GradeCourse` table.

```
CREATE VIEW CourseOfStudent 
AS
    SELECT CourseId, StudentId, NULL AS GradeId 
    FROM StudentRegisteredCourse
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CourseId, NULL AS StudentId, GradeId
    FROM GradeCourse;
```

I created a `CourseOfStudent` entity on EF and mapped it to the created view.

```
public class CourseOfStudent
{
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public Guid GradeId { get; set; }
}
```

and the `Student` entity is modified to have this collection.

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid GradeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CourseOfStudent> CoursesOfStudent{ get; set; }
}
```

My current problem is I don't know how to configure the `CoursesOfStudent` collection to have a foreign key, join on `StudentId` **OR** `GradeId`.

May someone have the same problem? Can you please give me some advice?

Comment: Have a base class ID and make studentId and GradeId inherited classes.